# extracting specific information from string with varying patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Reference':["PO: TK42-8", 
                                "PO GQ5-42", 
                                "PO:HEA-238/239", 
                                "PO: 4501005609  Purchaser: Mariana Toledo Blanco", 
                                "FITN7-26", 
                                "PO#CP4-62",
                                "PO 4501004752  Purchaser Yang Gao / Split from S94964",
                                "GUANGDONG YOULONG ELECTRICAL APPLIANCES CO.,LTD // PO#GQY6-17"]
                   })
```

From the above df, i've been trying, for a while with minimum success, to extract two pieces of info if available. Thereby creating 2 new columns as seen in the desired df below.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Reference':["PO: TK42-8", 
                                "PO GQ5-42", 
                                "PO:HEA-238/239", 
                                "PO: 4501005609  Purchaser: Mariana Toledo Blanco", 
                                "FITN7-26", 
                                "PO#CP4-62",
                                "PO 4501004752  Purchaser Yang Gao / Split from S94964",
                                "GUANGDONG YOULONG ELECTRICAL APPLIANCES CO.,LTD // PO#GQY6-17"],
                    
                    "PO":["TK42-8", "GQ5-42", "HEA-238/239", "4501005609", "FITN7-26","CP4-62", "4501004752", "GQY6-17" ],
                    "Purchaser":["", "", "", "Mariana Toledo Blanco", "","", "Yang Gao", "" ],
                   })
```

so far, i've been able to see a bit of success with:

```
df['PO'] = df['Reference'].str.extract(r"PO:.*?([ \w.\S-]+)")
df['Purchaser'] = df['Reference'].str.extract(r"Purchaser.*?([ \w.*]+)")
```

however, i'm missing how to correctly script for all the subtle possibilities for each case within each function parenthesis.

Comment: Looking at you dataframe I think you can use  `r'PO\W+(\S+)'` for extracting `PO` and for extracting `Purchaser` use `r'Purchaser\W+((?:\w+\s?)+)(?:\s|$)'`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma not quite. i'm closer with the following but still missing some values. ```df['PO'] = df['Reference'].str.extract(r"PO:\S|\s.*?([\w.\S-]+)")
df['Purchaser'] = df['Reference'].str.extract(r"Purchaser.*?([ \w.*]+)")```

Comment: One complication is on the entry of `"FITN7-26"`.  It doesn't have `PO` before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract POs with

```py
>>> df['Reference'].str.extract(r"(?:^(?=[A-Z\d/-]+$)|\bPO\W*)([A-Z\d/-]+)")
             0
0       TK42-8
1       GQ5-42
2  HEA-238/239
3   4501005609
4     FITN7-26
5       CP4-62
6   4501004752
7      GQY6-17
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [A-Z\d/-]+               any character of: 'A' to 'Z', digits
                               (0-9), '/', '-' (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                               the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PO                       'PO'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \W*                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                             9, _) (0 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z\d/-]+               any character of: 'A' to 'Z', digits (0-
                             9), '/', '-' (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Extract purchasers with

```py
>>> df['Reference'].str.extract(r"\bPurchaser\W+(\w(?:[\s\w]*\w)?)").fillna("")
                       0
0                       
1                       
2                       
3  Mariana Toledo Blanco
4                       
5                       
6               Yang Gao
7
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Purchaser                'Purchaser'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \W+                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                           9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\s\w]*                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                               \t, \f, and " "), word characters (a-
                               z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \w                       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: absolutely brilliant!. Many thanks for the explanation, it's really going to go a long way in learning this for the future.